# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'r'

Tags: python, python-2.7, readfile

So I'm reading a file and store it in variables as I go and when it get to this line:

```
valP=float(listEleVP)
```

it returns this:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'r'
```

This is the entire code:

```
def main():
    inFile=open('3weightcalc.in','r')
    i=0
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        a=line.split()

        for items in a:
            listEleVP=items[1]
            listEleVS=items[3]
            valP=float(listEleVP)
            valS=float(listEleVS)
            FinVal=float(valP*valS)
            txtA=items [0]
            txtB=items [2]
            print("On ",txtB,txtA,"would weigh ",FinVal,"pounds.")
    inFile.close()
main()
```

and this is the input (.in) file data:

```
Fred 179.0 Luna 0.1654
Layla 131 Mars 0.376
Pat 145.2 Neptune 1.14
END 0 0 0
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you printed out your variables, or done some other debugging to find out where the error is? Try some of these methods out before you post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the inner cicle isn't necessary:

```
def main():
    inFile=open('3weightcalc.in','r')
    i=0
    for line in inFile.readlines():
        items=line.split()

        listEleVP=items[1]
        listEleVS=items[3]
        valP=float(listEleVP)
        valS=float(listEleVS)
        FinVal=float(valP*valS)
        txtA=items [0]
        txtB=items [2]
        print("On ",txtB,txtA,"would weigh ",FinVal,"pounds.")
    inFile.close()
main()
```

Problem is that inside the inner cicle you iterate over the strings returned by `split`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> text = """Fred 179.0 Luna 0.1654
... Layla 131 Mars 0.376
... Pat 145.2 Neptune 1.14
... END 0 0 0"""
>>> for line in text.splitlines():
...     a = line.split()
...     for items in a:
...             print items[1], items[3]
... 
r d
7 .
u a
. 6
a l
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

You should instead do:

```
>>> for line in text.splitlines():
...     items = line.split()
...     print items[1], items[3]
... 
179.0 0.1654
131 0.376
145.2 1.14
0 0
```

Comment: Its a school assignment: I have to use the .in file.

Comment: @user2446048 I used a string because I didn't want to waste time saving the sample data to a file. Having `for line in inFile` or `for line in text.splitlines()` yields exactly the same results if the contents of `inFile` are the same of `text`.